# Expectation of a Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value

Let $W_t$ be a Wiener process. I'm having difficulty finding the next expected value:
$$E(max_{t \in [1, 2]}|W_t|)$$. Could you explain the solution to this problem, I don't even know where to start. The only thing i tried was to rewrite $|W_t|$. Since we know that $|W_t|$
equal in distribution to $sup_{s \leq t}W_s$, but after substitution it gave me nothing

Comment: You should probably choose where to ask the question, here or here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/75673/expectation-of-a-wiener-process

Comment: @Frido this question was deleted, since there were no answers at all

Comment: Yes I saw there were no answers. If you don't get any answers here you could still try cross-validated exchange.

Comment: @Frido thank you!